# Haskell type mismatch Int and [Int]

Tags: haskell, types, int, mismatch

I'm a beginner to Haskell. I'm trying to create a function which has two parameters: a character and a string.
This function is supposed to go through the string and check if the character given is in the string, and then return a list of integers representing the position of the characters in the string.

My code is:

```
tegnPose :: Char -> String -> [Int]
tegnPose c [] = []
tegnPose c (x:xs) = [if not (xs !! a == c)
 then [a] ++ tegnPose c xs
 else tegnPose c xs |a <- [0.. length xs - 1]]
```

Which is a recursive function with list comprehension.

The error I get:

```
Uke4.hs:14:7: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int]'
    * In the expression: [a] ++ tegnPose c xs
      In the expression:
        if not (xs !! a == c) then [a] ++ tegnPose c xs else tegnPose c xs
      In the expression:
        [if not (xs !! a == c) then
             [a] ++ tegnPose c xs
         else
             tegnPose c xs |
           a <- [0 .. length xs - 1]]
   |
14 |  then [a] ++ tegnPose c xs
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Uke4.hs:15:7: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `[Int]'
    * In the expression: tegnPose c xs
      In the expression:
        if not (xs !! a == c) then [a] ++ tegnPose c xs else tegnPose c xs
      In the expression:
        [if not (xs !! a == c) then
             [a] ++ tegnPose c xs
         else
             tegnPose c xs |
           a <- [0 .. length xs - 1]]
   |
15 |  else tegnPose c xs |a <- [0.. length xs - 1]]
```

I don't understand how the mismatch happens, as the recursive function should just run through.

Comment: The list comprehension returns a list by default. Trying to return yet another list inside gives you a list of lists, which is not what you want. I'd rewrite that to avoid the comprehension altogether.

Answer (score 5):

Here's why the mismatch happens.  First, note that a list comprehension that returns a list of type `[a]` must generate elements of type `a`, so you need the following to match:

```
example :: [Int] 

--  .-- the final value is "[Int]"
--  |
example = [ 2+x*y | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..5], x < y]
--          ^^^^^
--            |
--            `- therefore, this must be "Int"
```

In your example, the type signature for `tegnPose` implies that the list comprehension must return an `[Int]`, but the expression generating list elements, namely:

```
if ... then [a] ++ tegnPose c xs else tegnPose c cx
```

is clearly *not* returning a plain `Int` the way it's supposed to.

The first error message is indicating that actual type of the subexpression `[a] ++ tegnPos c xs` which is `[Int]` does not match the expected type of the result of the entire `if .. then .. else` expression which should have type `Int`.

If I understand your question correctly (i.e., return a list of the integer positions of each occurrence of a character in a string so that `tegnPose 'a' "abracadabra"` returns `[0,3,5,7,10]`, then you should *either* use recursion *or* a list comprehension, but not both.

Note that the non-recursive list comprehension:

```
tegnPose c xs = [a | a <- [0..length xs - 1]
```

*almost* does what you want.  All that's missing is testing the condition to see if the character at position `a` is a `c`.  If you don't know about using "guards" in list comprehensions, go look it up.

Alternatively, the recursive function without a list comprehension:

```
tegnPose c (x:xs) = if (x == c) then ??? : tegnPose c xs
                                else tegnPose c xs
tegnPose _ [] = []
```

also *almost* does what you want, except it's not obvious what to put in place of `???` to return a number indicating the current position.  If you write a recursive version with an extra parameter:

```
tp n c (x:xs) = if (x == c) then n : tp (???) c xs
                            else tp (???) c xs
tp _ _ [] = []
```

with the idea that you could define:

```
tegnPose c xs = tp 0 c xs
```

then you'd be closer, if only you could figure out what new value for `n` should go in place of the `???`.

More standard Haskell solutions might involve things like zips:

```
> zip [0..] "abracadabra"
[(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'r'),...]
```

and filters:

```
> filter (\(i,c) -> c == 'a') $ zip [0..] "abracadabra"
[(0,'a'),(3,'a'),...]
```

and maps:

```
> map fst $ filter (\(i,c) -> c == 'a') $ zip [0..] "abracadabra"
[0,3,5,7,10]
```

or looking in `Data.List` for a function that does what you want:

```
> elemIndices 'a' "abracadabra"
[0,3,5,7,10]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough response. I found it quite helpful =^)

Answer (score 1):

Just for some variety a simpler way of implementing this functionality with a single `foldr` could be;

```
import Data.Bool (bool)
charIndices :: Char -> String -> [Int]
charIndices c = foldr (\t r -> bool r (fst t : r) (snd t == c)) [] . zip [0..]

*Main> charIndices 't' "tektronix test and measurement instruments"
[0,3,10,13,29,34,40]
```

Explanation:

Type of `foldr` is `Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

It takes three parameters;

1. A function which accepts two parameters
2. An initial value of type `b`
3. A traversable data type which hold values of type `a`

an returns a single value of type `b`.

In this particular case our type `a` value is `Char` type, which makes `t a` a `String` type (due to type signature) and type `b` value is a list of integers `[Int]`.

The provided function as the first parameter is `(\t r -> bool r (fst t : r) (snd t == c))` which is very simple if you check [Data.bool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html). `bool` is a ternary operator of type `a -> a -> Bool -> a` which takes three arguments. In order they are negative result, positive result and condition. (negative is on the left as usual in Haskell). It checks if the current character is equal to our target character `c`, if so it returns `fst t : r` if not `r` (`r` means result). And finally `t` is the current tuple of the fed tuples list. The tuples list is constructed by `zip [0..] s` where `s` is not shown in the function definition due to partial application.

Comment: This does not look simpler to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner I have annexed an explanation to my answer.